# Modal popup with few questions once per time but without jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, local-storage

I'm trying to open modal popup on a page after load, that will ask user where is he from, country where he will get his items and choose currency.

I would like to both save his answers and close the popup. Site will reload (remembering answers). It should ask user like this probably once per month.

I found this solution:
    http://jsfiddle.net/Y2D67/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('popState') != 'shown'){
        $("#popup").delay(2000).fadeIn();
        localStorage.setItem('popState','shown')
    }

    $('#popup-close').click(function(e) // You are clicking the close button
    {
    $('#popup').fadeOut(); // Now the pop up is hidden.
    });
    $('#popup').click(function(e) 
    {
    $('#popup').fadeOut(); 
    });
});
```

But it uses jQuery. When I'm adding jQuery to my old website it goes crazy, almost blue screen. So, is there a way to make it (similar?) like the solution but without jQuery?

Comment: _"When im adding jQuery to my old website it goes crazy"_ = Whut? In what way? Also, did you try `jQuery.noConflict`? - but to answer your question, yes, you can do it without jQuery. jQuery _is just javsacript_ after all.

Comment: Its a SaaS old shop, so when i add some lib, it loses his mind and refuses to shop categories / slider. Any idea how to change it into pure JS?

Comment: Yes but I’d pretty much be rewriting your code for you. If you want to give it a go yourself, I’ll happily help you if you get stuck (assuming of course you post the code you made the attempt with).